# Gmail API .NET: How to request messages from one sender

Tags: .net, google-api, f#, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Currently, my boss wants me to write a software to get email from gmail and text it to a mobile number. However, the email needs to be from one sender only, my current solution is to use gmail-api get all the messages in the INBOX then filter using the `payload.header.Value`
I notice that when create the `UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest` I can add some filters such as

```
let emailListReq = service.Users.Messages.List( userId = "me")
emailListReq.LabelIds <- Google.Apis.Util.Repeatable<string>(["INBOX";"UNREAD"])    
emailListReq.IncludeSpamTrash <- Nullable<bool>(false)
```

I wonder is there a way to add the sender in to the filter such as

```
emailListReq.Sender <- "importSender@sender.com"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [search for messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) to find the messages you are looking for the string you sent to q is the same as the string you would use when searching in the gmail application so you can use that to test your search.

```
let emailListReq = service.Users.Messages.List( userId = "me")
emailListReq.Q <- "from:(importSender@sender.com)"
```

Note I am not a F# developer i am guessing at the code.

Comment: that works perfectly, didn't know I can include query in the request, thanks a bunch